# Convert string to float with exponencial numbers

Tags: u-sql

I need to convert a string to float
I need u-sql code.

the script could be an exponencial like 10^2

I tried Float.Convert but not works.

I expect

```
convert(10^2) = 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your own format is You will need to write a C# function to do that.

You can write code behind

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/04/calling-u-sql-stored-procedures-with-c-code-behind/

or functions

https://sqlplayer.net/2017/10/functions-in-the-usql-the-hidden-gem-in-the-summer-2017-update/

Comment: I have my own format, but i need to write a dll code?

Comment: No, check the second link.

Answer (score 1):

An example using U-SQL inline functions:

```
DECLARE @func Func <string,int?> = (s) =>{int x = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('^')[0]); int y = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('^')[1]); return x*y;};

DECLARE @inputFile string = @"\input\input36.csv";
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"\output\output.csv";

@input =
    EXTRACT rowId int,
            expo string
    FROM @inputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv();


@output =
    SELECT *,
           @func(expo) AS z
    FROM @input;


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

Using this [sample file](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/e780f5d007708bc8ce273336073cd355), I got these results:

[image: results]