# Single letter functions in usql

Tags: u-sql

I have found usages of single functions such as T(), A() and D().

For example, this from the usql notebook https://legacy.gitbook.com/book/saveenr/usql-tutorial/details

```
@departments =
  SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES
      (31, "Sales"),
      (33, "Engineering"),
      (34, "Clerical"),
      (35, "Marketing")
    ) AS D( DepID, DepName );
```

Can someone please help me understand the meaning of these single letter functions or what they are?

Comment: Hi @Rahul - any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

U-SQL has the ability to create inline functions which are covered in great detail here:

https://sqlplayer.net/2017/10/functions-in-the-usql-the-hidden-gem-in-the-summer-2017-update/

You can do similar in Databricks, eg here's an example using Scala based on this [U-SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112242/convert-string-to-float-with-exponencial-numbers/54524950#54524950):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr, split, udf}
import scala.math._

// Define the function
val x = udf((s: Long, t: Long) => pow(s,t))

// Setup
val df = Seq( ( 1, "10^2" ), ( 2, "12^12" ), ( 3, "33^3") )
  .toDF("rowId", "expo")


// Use the function
df
  .withColumn( "col1", split( $"expo", "\\^").getItem(0) )
  .withColumn( "col2", split( $"expo", "\\^").getItem(1) )
  .withColumn( "col3", expr("pow(col1, col2)") )
  .withColumn( "col4", x($"col1", $"col2") )
  .show()
```

I would generally recommend longer function names however, in the interests of making code self-documenting.